# Как импортировать изображения в хорошем разрешение WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Хочу импортировать изображение в VisualStudio, но в итоге оно получается **очень** плохого качества:

[image: Приложение и референс]

*Приложение и референс*

Comment: [Откуда «мыло» в WPF и как с ним бороться](https://habr.com/ru/post/216833/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я нагуглил по запросу "visual studio image blurred wpf"

```
<Image Name="ImageOrderedList"
       Source="images/OrderedList.png"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" //добавь вот это
/>
```

как второй вариант - `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"`

Comment: Второй вариант помог